# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied using Python, but I can't see why?

Tags: python-2.7, file

I have been coding an App that needs to write some lines to a directory in Linux, but the output returned keeps showing the following error:

```
File "/home/p4user/flexclone/main/demo/flex.py", line 1305, in p4config
    fh = open(path + "/.p4config", "w")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/p4flex/rickclone36/.p4config'
```

The user does have permission for this directory, and I have tried various filenames which exists and do not exist yet. I have been spinning around for the past 36 hours and this is a roadblock. Here is the code snippet causing the issue (I have throughly traced through the code snipped too):

```
def p4config(self, path, client):
    p4config = os.getenv('P4CONFIG', '.p4config')
    p4port = self.call.getPort()
    p4user = self.call.getUser()
    fh = open(path + "/.p4config", "w")
    if fh:
```

The error occurs is seen at the `fh=open()` line. Does anyone have suggestions, or indications why the block may be occurring? When as a user I just touch files, it's all fine.

Thanks

Comment: Is the file already open somewhere else? Also, might want to use `os.path.join()` instead of `+` concatenating the path.

Comment: Is `.p4config` a file, or a directory? Your question seems a bit conflicted on that point. Does it exist already? What are the permissions on it?